# Reload/Refresh automatically PHP on user input

Tags: php, html

I have this form that feeds into a table displayed on my site.

Currently, when the user inputs and submits the data, the user needs to refresh the page for the new data to be displayed.

Is it possible for the table to be auto-refreshed every time the user presses ENTER or submits the data from the form?

```
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th><div class="search-box">
        <iframe name="votar" style="display:none;"></iframe>
        <form action="protected_page.php" method="post" target="votar">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Busca tu producto" name="producto" size="60" />

        <div class="result"></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="usuario" value="<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']); ?>" /></th>
    <th><input type="submit" name="mandar"/>
    <th><input type='submit' name='reload' value='UPDATE' />    
               </form>
</th>

  </tr>
</table>
  <?php
   if(isset($_POST['mandar'])){ 

      $sql_man="INSERT INTO busca (producto, username) VALUES ('$_POST[producto]','$_POST[usuario]')";

      $mysqli->query($sql_man);   

        header("Location: /protected_page.php"); 

      } 
      if(isset($_POST['reload'])){          
        header("Location: /protected_page.php"); 
      }
     ?>   
  </div>
```

Comment: you can use multiple submit in a form...

Comment: What exactly you want? Such an ambiguous question.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to reload the page.

```
echo"<script>window.location.reload();</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

echo "window.location.reload(true);";